# Can you limit the files that telegraf tail to prevent linux opened files limit?

Tags: linux, docker-compose, influxdb, tail, telegraf

Before nothing thanks for the help, my problem is with a telegraf that writes from csv directory to influxdb, the csv generate one row every 10 minutes from that day and the next generates another csv with updates every 10 minutes.The csv directory is growing and the telegraf tailed files are more and more, im thinking an aproach to limit the tailed files in order to prevent linux opened files errors that make influx crash.

This is the error that crashes my influxdb

```
influxdb     | ts=2022-06-01T10:51:01.773649Z lvl=info msg="Cache snapshot (start)" 
log_id=0aohXOVl000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 op_name=tsm1_cache_snapshot op_event=start
influxdb     | ts=2022-06-01T10:51:01.774189Z lvl=info msg="Error writing snapshot from 
compactor" log_id=0aohXOVl000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 op_name=tsm1_cache_snapshot 
error="compaction in progress: open 
/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/8f0b7f9951a1ea0b/autogen/85/000000987-000000001.tsm.tmp: too many 
open files"
```

Any help is apreciated